# For non negative integers $\sum{P\left(X\geq x\right)}=\int{\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x}$

Tags: probability, definite-integrals, summation, indefinite-integrals

I want to show that for non negative integers $X$ we have $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{P\left(X\geq x\right)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x}$$

I know that $P\left(X\geq x\right)=1-P\left(X < x\right)$ and $F\left(x\right)=P\left(X\leq x\right)$. So I rewrite the summation like this:
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{\left(1-P\left(X < x\right)\right)}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\left(1-P\left(X \leq x\right)\right)}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)}$$

But I don't know how to show it's that integral. Would someone please help?

Comment: For non-negative integers $x$ we have the identity $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf1(x\geq n)$. For non-negative reals $x$ we have the identity $x=\int_0^\infty\mathbf1(x>t)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t$. We can get the result by applying $\mathbb E$ to these equations (though technically you need Fubini to justifying swapping sums/integrals with $\mathbb E$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty} (1-F(x)) dx &= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \int_k^{k+1} (1-F(x)) dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \int_k^{k+1} (1-\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)) dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \int_k^{k+1} \mathbb{P}(X > x) dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \int_k^{k+1} \mathbb{P}(X > k) dx\\
\end{align*}

the last step coming from the fact that since $X$ takes only integer values, then for every $x \in [k, k+1)$, the events $\lbrace X > x \rbrace$ and  $\lbrace X > k \rbrace$ are equal. So
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{+\infty} (1-F(x)) dx &= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \int_k^{k+1} \mathbb{P}(X > k) dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > k) \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}(X \geq k+1) \\
\end{align*}

i.e. finally $$\boxed{\int_0^{+\infty} (1-F(x)) dx = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}(X \geq k) }$$